# size of extent on LVM2

Tags: linux, performance, lvm, partition

in LVM1 there was a limit of 65k extends. So size of extent had to been chosen carefully between wasted space on partitions (to big extent) and maximal possible size of logical volume (too small extent). in lvm2 (according to http://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/5992-4589/apa.html) the limit is ~16 million extents. so the default size of 4mb gives ~60TB of LV size.

so is there any point in making the extent larger than 4-16mb on a desktop? is there any performance degradation or other costs of having big number of extents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the vgcreate man page:

```
If the volume group metadata uses lvm1 format, extents can vary in size from 8KiB to 
16GiB and there is a limit of 65534 extents in each logical volume.  The default of 4 
MiB leads to a maximum logical volume size of around 256GiB.

If  the volume group metadata uses lvm2 format those restrictions do not apply, but 
having a large number of extents will slow down the tools but have no impact on I/O
performance to the logical volume.  The smallest PE is 1KiB

The 2.4 kernel has a limitation of 2TiB per block device.
```

I read this as -s (or --physicalextentsize) is a backwards compatibility switch.  Has no real performance implications in LVM2 with the exception of the LVM tools.

This also governs the granularity of LV size increases.  i.e. a VG with 64GB extents can only be grown in chunks of 64GB...